# Grab $(this) element's html and insert into $scope.variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to grab the `buttons` html with `.html()` and insert into `$scope.player`. The button is calling the `choosePlayer()` function with `ng-click` but it is not working.

Here's the codepen link: http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/ojJrRp

HTML

```
<body ng-app="ticTacToe" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <h1>TIC TAC TOE</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper" class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-click="move(cell)" ng-repeat="cell in cells" class="col-xs-4 square text-center">
      {{cell.value}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>CHOOSE A SHAPE</h1>
    <button ng-click="choosePlayer()" class="btn btn-red" id="choose-cross">✖</button>
    <button ng-click="choosePlayer()" class="btn btn-green" id="choose-circle">&#9711;</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module("ticTacToe", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  var cell = $(".square");
  $scope.player = "";
  var cross = "×";
  var circle = "◯";

  $scope.choosePlayer = function(){
    $scope.player = $(this).html();
  }

  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];

  $scope.move = function(cell){
    cell.value = $scope.player;
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the [`$event` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) in the `ng-click()` directive:

```
<button ng-click="choosePlayer($event)" class="btn btn-red" id="choose-cross">✖</button>
<button ng-click="choosePlayer($event)" class="btn btn-green" id="choose-circle">&#9711;</button>
```

And then access [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the element in your controller:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOPemZ)

Without jQuery:

```
$scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = e.currentTarget.innerText;
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = $(e.currentTarget).text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. I am still new to angular and jquery so I am learning something new everyday.